# Where is DNA during the process of RNA extraction using Trisure?

Tags: dna, rna, rna-sequencing, protocol

Where is DNA during the process of RNA extraction using Trisure described [here](https://www.bioline.com/uk/downloads/dl/file/id/1189/trisure_fact_sheet.pdf/%22here%22)? Given that DNA is also a nucleic acid, should I expect the isolated RNA to also contain DNA? However, Bioline claims RNA 'with 
virtually no genomic DNA contamination'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expectedly, they don’t really want to tell you what TRIsure is. What they do say is that DNA is found in the organic or interphase after extraction whereas RNA partitions to the aqueous phase. This is almost certainly some variant of [acid phenol extraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_guanidinium_thiocyanate-phenol-chloroform_extraction). As confirmation, the MSDS lists phenol, ammonium thiocyanate, guanidinium thiocyanate, glycerol and citric acid as its components.

Comment: But why does the DNA end up in the organic phase? Isn't it as hydrophilic as RNA?

Comment: I found this in the link you provided: 'The nucleic acids (RNA and/or DNA) partition into the aqueous phase, while protein partitions into the organic phase. The pH of the mixture determines which nucleic acids get purified.[3] Under acidic conditions (pH 4-6), DNA partitions into the organic phase while RNA remains in the aqueous phase. Under neutral conditions (pH 7-8), both DNA and RNA partition into the aqueous phase.'

Comment: @charlesdarwin That’s a good question to which [I don’t know the answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56471/6307).